# creating a mosaic like pattern with css grid / flex

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, grid

I have a long list of childs and I would like to render them like the following pattern and repeat the pattern. Is there anyway to create this pattern using css Grid / Flex only

[view the pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0th5Z.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new answer since I misunderstood your request at first. Here's dynamic code that will repeat the pattern, regardless of # of children:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;

    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.block {
    padding: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.block:nth-child(14n+1),
.block:nth-child(14n+12){
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block block1">1</div>
    <div class="block block2">2</div>
    <div class="block block3">3</div>
    <div class="block block4">4</div>
    <div class="block block5">5</div>
    <div class="block block6">6</div>
    <div class="block block7">7</div>
    <div class="block block8">8</div>
    <div class="block block9">9</div>
    <div class="block block10">10</div>
    <div class="block block11">11</div>
    <div class="block block12">12</div>
    <div class="block block13">13</div>
    <div class="block block14">14</div>
    <div class="block block15">15</div>
    <div class="block block16">16</div>
    <div class="block block17">17</div>
    <div class="block block18">18</div>
    <div class="block block19">19</div>
    <div class="block block20">20</div>
    <div class="block block21">21</div>
    <div class="block block22">22</div>
    <div class="block block23">23</div>
    <div class="block block24">24</div>
    <div class="block block25">25</div>
    <div class="block block26">26</div>
    <div class="block block27">27</div>
    <div class="block block28">28</div>
    <div class="block block29">29</div>
    <div class="block block30">30</div>
    <div class="block block31">31</div>
    <div class="block block32">32</div>
    <div class="block block33">33</div>
    <div class="block block34">34</div>
    <div class="block block35">35</div>
    <div class="block block36">36</div>
    <div class="block block37">37</div>
    <div class="block block38">38</div>
    <div class="block block39">39</div>
    <div class="block block40">40</div>
    <div class="block block41">41</div>
    <div class="block block42">42</div>
    <div class="block block43">43</div>
    <div class="block block44">44</div>
    <div class="block block45">45</div>
    <div class="block block46">46</div>
    <div class="block block47">47</div>
    <div class="block block48">48</div>
    <div class="block block49">49</div>
    <div class="block block50">50</div>
    <div class="block block51">51</div>
    <div class="block block52">52</div>
    <div class="block block53">53</div>
    <div class="block block54">54</div>
    <div class="block block55">55</div>
    <div class="block block56">56</div>
  </div>
```